# Removing specific rows from contact table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with a app in which user can select contacts from phone contact and send them message.i am getting cursor for phone contacts like this`

```
Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
```

i am using this cursor in cursoradapter to show it in listview,
and i have a database which stores the contacts which user selects.now i want to show only that contacts in listview that are not in my database, i mean i want something like `select name,phonenumber from contact except select name,phonenumber from mydatabase` and get this result in a cursor which i will use in cursoradapter. is this possible? how can i do that,please help me out.thanks in advance! .

Answer (score 0):

The 4th argument is your 'WHERE' part, so you can add it there.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)

If that doesn't work out, you can always just loop through the result and filter it out programatically.

Comment: Check out http://www.vogella.com/ for some good beginner tutorials, including topics as managing and querying your own databae in Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete any specific contact then you have to use following query

```
  Cursor cr = getContentResolver().delete(url, where, selectionArgs);
```

or if want to delete all contacts then

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null);
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    try{
        String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
        System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
        cr.delete(uri, null, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for reply, i think i am not clear in my question , but i don't want to delete contacts, i just want to select only those rows which are not in my database, it will be helpful if you give me a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since the contacts and your database are not in the same database, you cannot combine their data in the same query directly. Some ways around it:

1. Filter unwanted rows from the contacts result set in code. E.g. if the name and number match your database, just move the cursor to the next row.
2. Construct an exclusion list from your database first and use it with the contacts database query, e.g.

   ```
   select name || ':magicseparator:' || number from mydatabase;
   ```

   Where `:magicseparator:` is just some random string to help separate names and numbers and prevent name-number collisions.

   Then construct a comma-separated string list out of these results and pass then to the selection (WHERE) criteria in your contacts query:

   ```
    "name || ':magicseparator:' || number not in (" + yourCommaSeparatedExclusionList + ")"
   ```